# ERR wrong number of arguments for 'zadd' command

Tags: go, redis

I have found this Error:

```
ERR wrong number of arguments for 'zadd' command in golang.
```

This is my code:

```
defaultPriority:type String
mb.MessageID:type string
mb.EndpointID: type string

    _, err = mbDal.redisClient.ZAdd(mb.EndpointID, redis.Z{Score: defaultPriority, Member: mb.MessageID})
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("failed to add mailbox id %s in redis; error %v", mb.MessageID, err)
        }
```

How can I fix this error message?

Answer (score 0):

[`zadd` is used in `go-redis/redis`](https://github.com/go-redis/redis/search?q=zadd&unscoped_q=zadd), and is [defined here](https://github.com/go-redis/redis/blob/9d1e8a566f9fb2f516b0ba2832f65ce6aa57ca9e/commands.go#L1665-L1670)

```
// Redis `ZADD key score member [score member ...]` command.
func (c cmdable) ZAdd(key string, members ...*Z) *IntCmd {
```

Double-check your `go.mod` dependencies list.
10 months ago, in go-redis v7 (instead of current v8), the [signature for that function was](https://github.com/go-redis/redis/commit/685d8922de03a2f4e2143989ce945e0253d27049):

```
 func (c *cmdable) ZAdd(key string, members ...Z) *IntCmd {
```

It used Z instead of (today) *Z.

In your case, you should pass:

```
&redis.Z{Score: defaultPriority, Member: mb.MessageID}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to insert `redis.Z{Score: [an int value], Member: code}` to `Redis sorted set` and it failed with that error.

So I checked my logic and find out someone calling my method with `code` as an empty string. in my case first insert was successful but after that, all insert failed with that error.

- I'm using `github.com/go-redis/redis v6.15.6`